# PyPy cleanup for redistribution

Tags: pypy

How can I cleanup PyPy after building it? Which parts are absolutely critical and which parts can I safely delete?

Obviously it's necessary to remove all version controll related files and folders (`.gitignore`, `.hg`, `.hgignore`, `.hgsubstate`, `.hgtags`) but there must be some more directories that can be painlessly removed.

Hint: There was a description of all directories on http://doc.pypy.org/ it could be helpfull but unfortunately I just can't find it now.

Comment: http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/#pypy-directory-cross-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the PyPy team, we use the following script:

```
cd pypy/tool/release
./package.py ../../.. pypy-VERSION-PLATFORM
```

which puts its results in /tmp/usession-YOURNAME/build/.  This is a complete copy of everything that is needed in order to install or redistribute a binary.